# VBA: clear data from an object(Array) (SAP Object in VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I am an SAP developer with little knowledge of VBA.
I am creating an VBA to post data to SAP using a BAPI. The coding is working fine & I am able to post data into SAP. My problem is I have several rows in my excel, I have to loop the rows one by one & upload data in SAP, after each upload i need to clear the contents, I am unaware of what syntax needs to be used to clear the data of the object variable. Below is the code snippet..

```
Set objbapicontrol = CreateObject("SAP.Functions")
Set objbapi = objbapicontrol.Add("BAPI_PO_CREATE1")
Set poheader = objbapi.exports.Item("POHEADER")
Set poitems = objbapi.tables.Item("POITEM")

For Each row In [POHEAD].Rows    '##PO Header
 If row.Columns(row.ListObject.ListColumns("SAP_PO_NUM").Index).Value = "" Then
    ponum = (row.Columns(row.ListObject.ListColumns("PONumber").Index).Value)
    poheader.Value("COMP_CODE") = (row.Columns(row.ListObject.ListColumns("COCD").Index).Value)
i = "00001"
    n = 1
'###Loop Detail
 For Each rowd In [PODET].Rows         '##PO Detail
     If (rowd.Columns(rowd.ListObject.ListColumns("PONumber").Index).Value) = ponum Then
     poitem = (rowd.Columns(rowd.ListObject.ListColumns("Itemnumber").Index).Value)
     poitems.Rows.Add
     poitemsx.Rows.Add
     poitems.Value(n, "PO_ITEM") = i
     poitems.Value(n, "MATERIAL") = Material
Next          '##PO Detail
  returnfunc = objbapi.call
  ponumber = objbapi.imports("EXPPURCHASEORDER")
  Set retmess = objbapi.tables.Item("RETURN")
Set poitems = Nothing
next
```

I am using the code `"Set POITEMS = NOTHING"` but again when I set the object, the previous data is not cleared & duplicate enteries are created in SAP

Thanks in Advance!!
Regards,
Anil Malhotra

Answer (score 0):

try using Set poitems = objbapi.tables.Item("POITEM") under the For loop.

set poitems= NOTHING will destroy the object but sometimes do not clear data. I faced this issue and was solved by moving the object creating code to the loop.

Hope it helps :)